# Combining two results of datasets into one

Tags: c#, web-services, dataset, datalist

I have created a webservice which returns two datasets(return type) as results.
Is it possible to combine two datasets results into one so that I can display it on one datalist? I try using `arraylist` but it returns nothing in `datalist`.

`GetDepartureFlightsDetails()` and `getDepartureFlights()` both returns a dataset values.

Below is the method i use to retrieve the webservice results.

```
public ArrayList GetDepartureFlightsDetails(String departurecountry, String arrivalcountry, DateTime departuredate)   
{
    DLSA datalayerTS = new DLSA();
    DLJS datalayerJW = new DLJS();

    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

    array.Add(datalayerSA.GetDepartureFlightsDetails(departurecountry, arrivalcountry, departuredate));
    array.Add(datalayerJW.getDepartureFlights(departurecountry, arrivalcountry, departuredate));
    return array;
}
```

Comment: FredHomme change your declaration of array to something like this ArrayList arList = new ArrayList(); should would make it easy and more readable in regards to your return array not being confused as Array vs the return Type being of type ArrayList just a suggestion

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the wrong naming.

Comment: just a suggestion FredHomme

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [DataSet.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
firstDataSet.Merge(secondDataSet);
```

---

Update:

```
public DataSet GetDepartureFlightsDetails(String departurecountry, String arrivalcountry, DateTime departuredate)
{
    DLSA datalayerTS = new DLSA();
    DLJS datalayerJW = new DLJS();

    var firstDataSet = datalayerSA.GetDepartureFlightsDetails(departurecountry, arrivalcountry, departuredate));
    var secondDataSet = datalayerJW.getDepartureFlights(departurecountry, arrivalcountry, departuredate));
    firstDataSet.Merge(secondDataSet);

    return firstDataSet;
}
```

Comment: careful about duplicate rows in new datatable when merging.

Comment: how do i add the dataset results to a dataset? 
DataSet first = new DataSet();
Then?

Comment: The question says "GetDepartureFlightsDetails() and getDepartureFlights() both returns a dataset values", and I thought that means they return DataSets. That is not the case? What is the _exact_ return type of those methods?

Comment: their return type is DataSet.
so i put
return GetDepartureFlightsDetails().Merge(getDepartureFlights())
?
but it returns a error "(Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet'")"

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make a wrapper Class and use `List<>` of the wrapper class ,
rather than `Datasets`.